# External dependencies install fails for REDHAWK3.0.0 on RHEL8

Tags: yum, redhawksdr, rhel8, dnf

Having set up the local YUM repository for REDHAWK v3.0.0 on RHEL8 per [manual instructions](https://redhawksdr.org/3.0.0/html/Install/redhawk-yum-repo.html), I find that there are no matches for `python-omniORB`, `omniORBpy-libs`. Indeed, they are not present in the `redhawk-3.0.0-el7-x86_64` directory. I did install `python3-omniORB` through `pip` but am struggling with `omniORBpy-libs`.

I noticed that `omniORBpy-libs-4.2.3-0.54929.el7.x86_64` is included in the REDHAWKv2.8 release. Will using that version cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

The yum group installs pull in the dependencies they need.
So, you don't need to install the dependencies separately.
I had success on CentOS 7 with:

```
yum groupinstall "REDHAWK Runtime"
yum groupinstall "REDHAWK Development"
```

You mentioned that you might try to install `python3-omniORB` and `omniORBpy-libs` from sources outside of `redhawk-yum-3.0.0-el7-x86_64.tar.gz`.
Before you run the group installs, I recommend you first uninstall those.

It looks like the list of dependencies from the documentation all install except for the two you mentioned.
I suspect that `python3-omniORB` is just missing the `3` in the documentation.
I'm not sure about `omniORBpy-libs`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was not able to resolve the omniORB dependency and ended up switching to a CentOS 7.9 install. For anyone else who reads this, I *do not recommend* attempting to install REDHAWK 3.0.0 on RHEL8. 

The word in the street is that the long-term transition target is Rocky Linux 8.4.